# How qt handle multi time signal slot connection?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, qtimer

I write this code :

```cpp
void my_qobject_class::f ()
{
    m_timer->start(duration);
    m_timer->setSingleShot(true);

    QObject::connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this]
    {
        emit its_down();

        const auto new_duration = calculate_duration();
        m_timer->start(new_duration);
        m_timer->setSingleShot(false);

        emit sec2_start();

        QObject::connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this]
        {
            emit sec2_emit();
        });
    });
}
```

And i want to know ''How Qt handle multi-time signal/slot connection ?'' it's possible to goes wrong ?

Comment: Each timer shot does not destroy connections between QTimer and you lambdas, so that your first lambda will fire on each timeout. Futhermore, each time it will connect an additional instance of second lambda to the timer. So that sec2_emit will be sent twice on third timeout, thrice on fourth and so on.

Comment: @AlexanderZavertan, And how can i fix it ?